# How can I set dynamic value in Jmeter Loop Controller from beanshell post processor?

Tags: jmeter

Bean-shell Post-Processor code:

```
int totalElements= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("totalElements"));
vars.put("totalElements", String.valueOf(totalElements));
```

In loop controller, I used these following but couldn't get this value.

```
${__javaScript(parseInt(${totalElements})}; 
${__javaScript(parseInt("${totalElements}"))};
${__V(totalElements)};
${totalElements};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try variable name without semi-colon:

[image]

The other issue is if variable `totalElements` for some reason was not defined, the statement `vars.get("totalElements")` will return `null`, and parsing `Integer.parseInt(null)` will cause an exception, which will cause a failure of the sampler. If that's a desired behavior, fine, but if not, you can do this:

```
String value = vars.get("totalElements");
int totalElements = (value != null) ? Integer.parseInt(value) : 0;
vars.put("totalElements", String.valueOf(totalElements));
```

So if variable could not be retrieved, `totalElements` is set to 0, and thus loop will not run. But sampler will not fail either.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this posted problem. Worked following the below script:

```
int totalElements= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("totalElements"));
vars.put("totalElements", String.valueOf(totalElements));
```

Then I have used `${__javaScript("${totalElements}")}` in Loop Controller and worked properly.